# how to write a Dynamic SOQL query using condition operator '?'

Tags: apex, soql, rest

client requesting data with some parameters like startdate, enddate, status. based on those parameters i have to return results in httpGet method.

1.if status!=null it will add status =:object.status in where condition

2.if startdate!=null && enddate!=null then it add startDate =: object.startDate AND endDate =: object.endDate;

my base query will be like

```
string query = 'select id, name, owner.name, owner.id, createddate from case';
```

please help me.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: base query will be like above if all parameters are null it will return the data based on base query . if parametrs are not null then it has to  add parameters in where condition and returns data. here Object.status (object is a reference of wrapper class which holds parameters from client)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are already making dynamic SOQL here So you need to add these parameter in your base query.

You need to store them in variable and needs to use them as direct object reference won't work here

```
String obStatus = object.status;
DateTime obStartdate = object.startDate;
DateTime obEnddate = object.endDate;
boolean whereflag = true;
if(status != null) {
query += ' WHERE status =:obStatus  '; // you might want to check object.status is not null
whereflag = false;
}
if(startdate!=null && enddate!=null) {
   if(whereflag )
      query += ' WHERE startDate =: obStartdate  AND endDate =: obEnddate ';
   else 
      query += ' And startDate =: obStartdate  AND endDate =: obEnddate ';// And or Or it depends also you want to check object.startDate and object.endDate
}
```

Similar you can add more parameter if needed and can perform the SOQL.

Comment: Tushar thank you, can we write query like below                                     
 query+= String.isNotBlank(object.status) ?  'AND Status =: object.status' : '';

Comment: @ApexCode yes you can but be careful about spaces and adding where or AND

Comment: @TusharSharma object.startDate won't work, by the way. You can only reference simple variables.

Comment: @sfdcfox I thought they will work. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox and Tushar Sharma. How can we use query for object.startDate and object.endDate ...please help me

Comment: @ApexCode they are already in Query. Please explain in detail what you need here.

Comment: query+= String.isNotBlank(object.status) ? 'AND Status =: object.status' : ''; ...is it works for                                                                                              startDate and endDate like startDate!=null ?'And createdDate >=:object.startDate' ...can we use like this way

Comment: @ApexCode do you want similar syntax for the start and end date? Also why you are not using normal if condition.

Comment: Yes Tushar similar code like above i mentioned...

Comment: `Query+= whereflag ? ' Where ' : ' AND '; query+= (startdate!=null && enddate!=null) ? '  startDate =: obStartdate  AND endDate =: obEnddate ' : '';` @ApexCode